# How to determine the size of each dimension of multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c#

```
int[,,] moreInts = { {{10,20,30}, {60,70,80}, {111,222,333}} };
```

How do I retrieve the size of each dimension in this multi-dimensional array when it is defined and initialized in the same statement?  I know by looking that it is [1,3,3], but how do I determine that programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GetLength method can be used to return the size of a array's dimension

```
moreInts.GetLength(0);
moreInts.GetLength(1);
moreInts.GetLength(2);
```

This is the correct way for an array declared [,,]. For arrays declared [][][], where each could have a different number of dimensions, KeithS's method is correct.

Comment: +1, thank you.  I missed that .GetLength() took a parameter and that is what the parameter would be for in the function (thought it was just returning the same thing as .Length, which was 9).  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code snippet:

```
int[, ,] moreInts = { { { 10, 20, 30 }, { 60, 70, 80 }, { 111, 222, 333 } } };

List<int> indicies = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < moreInts.Rank; i++)
    indicies.Add(moreInts.GetUpperBound(i) + 1);

indicies.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Hope this helps.